# Sending mail in web2py with GMX

Tags: python, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to send a mail in web2py but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
def send_email():
    from gluon.tools import Mail
    mail = Mail()
    mail.settings.tls = True
    mail.settings.server = 'mail.gmx.net:587'
    mail.settings.sender = 'scl_mail@gmx.ch'
    mail.settings.login  = 'scl_mail@gmx.ch:password'
    prova = mail.send(to = 'email', subject = 'Hello', message = 'You have received a mail.')
    
    return {'prova':prova}
```

Does anyone have any ideea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you could try to wrap the mail.send in a try except to see if that gives more insights in your problem. `try: prova = mail.send(to = 'email', subject = 'Hello', message = 'You have received a mail.') return {'prova':prova} except Exception as e: return {'error': str(e)}`